# How can I reset the nether chunks below y level 128 with MCA Selector?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I run a **Spigot 1.15.2** server and as **1.16** is coming closer I had to think about resetting the nether for us. The thing is that people have built gold farms and other nether mob farms above the bedrock ceiling which is **y 128**. I want to specifically reset the chunks that are below y 128.

I came across this question: [Reset nether but preserve above ceiling?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/369585/reset-nether-but-preserve-above-ceiling)

But the answer to this post was to use NBT explorer for every single chunk and I find it pretty hard to do it that way.

I want to use MCA selector to only reset those chunks. Is that possible?

EDIT: Also if there isn't a way then how do I copy only the y value of certain chunks in NBTExplorer? If I copy and paste the chunks then it would also copy the part below y 128